# Can the proof for the following 4 cases be simplified to 2 cases?

Tags: logic, inequality, proof-writing

Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite and disjoint sets. Suppose we are required to prove the following:

$|X|\ge 0 \text{ and } |Y|\ge 0 \Rightarrow Q $ where $Q$ is some statement.

Therefore, I know I need to consider the following 4 cases separately:

1. $|X|=0 \text{ and } |Y|=0$
2. $|X|=0 \text{ and } |Y|>0$
3. $|X|>0 \text{ and } |Y|=0$
4. $|X|>0 \text{ and } |Y|>0$

I get the impression (based on what I read in my text) that I can actually just consider the following 2 cases separately:

1. $ |X|=0 \text{ or } |Y|= 0$
2. $|X|>0 \text{ and } |Y|>0$

Is this true, in general or only in certain cases (and if so, why?) or did I just misinterpreted my text?

EDIT:

An example of $Q$:

$|X\cup Y| = |X| + |Y|$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I've provided an example of $Q$.

Comment: Well, that $Q$ is not even true, unless you know the two are disjoint...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Noted. Nevertheless, the 4 separate cases to be considered can be simplified to considering two separate cases, right (based on Omnomnomnom's answer)

Comment: @mauna you seem not to read other answers :)

Comment: I honestly misread the question, so my first comment is incorrect about it not being true in general - definite that answer is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that "$|X|=0 \text{ or } |Y|= 0$" is logically the same as "1, 2 or 3" from the 4 cases that you've listed.

So, in your second consideration, you consider 3 out of the 4 cases simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

The statements $\left[\left|X\right|\geq0\wedge\left|Y\right|\geq0\right]\Rightarrow Q$
and $Q$ are equivalent. So proving the first statement comes to the same as proving the second.

Underlying reason: statement $\left|X\right|\geq0\wedge\left|Y\right|\geq0$ is true.

Answer (score 1):

You need not consider any cases; you only need to prove that Q is true.